# My cog is not working for my bot in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is the code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class roll(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def roll(self, ctx, output):
        count, size = output.split("d")
        size = int(size)
        count = int(count)
        counter = 0
        rolltotal = 0
        while counter < count:
            result = randint(1, size)
            rolltotal += result
            counter += 1
        eject = "You rolled {} on a {}!".format(rolltotal, output)
        await ctx.send(eject)

    @roll.error
    async def roll_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance (error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please specify the size of the dice and ho many dice you\'re rolling EX: 1d20')
            await ctx.message.delete()
            print(f'{ctx.author.name} tried to roll dnd dice but didn\'t specify an argument in {ctx.guild.name}')
        elif isinstance (error, commands.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please specify the size of the dice and ho many dice you\'re rolling EX: 1d20')
            await ctx.message.delete()
            print(f'{ctx.author.name} tried to roll dnd dice but gave a bad argument in {ctx.guild.name}')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(roll(bot))
```

I cant figure out what is wrong with this cog I have other cogs that send messages fine but this one dosent for some reason

Answer (score 1):

In the command decorator, set the name of the command: `@commands.command(name="roll")`

Answer (score 0):

I did not import random and my ide was jut not showing that there was an error so time for a new ide